# SQL Server -> 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' Collation -> Varchar Column -> Languages Supported

Tags: sql-server-2008, unicode, collation, codepages

All,

We are using SQL Server 2008 with Collation Setting as 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'. We are using Varchar column to store textual data. We know that we cannot store Double Byte data in Varchar column and hence cannot support languages like Japanese and Chinese without converting it to NVarchar.

However, will it be safe to say that all Single Byte Characters can be stored in Varchar column without any problem? If yes then from where can I get the list of languages which needs Single Byte for storage and the list of languages which needs double byte?

Any assistance in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of characters is defined by the [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) (and sort order too)

Basically, Western European languages with this collation. You won't have Romanian, say, nor will you have correct Spanish sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 

Is there any link where I can get the list or linkage of supported characters to the Language. This is needed since we need to communicate to the external party about how many languages can be supported with the current database structure (which internally uses Varchar columns).

Comment: I don't know one. But why not loop through i 32 -> 255 and do CHAR(i)...?